# An action registered event should be called before page_load but it is not happening why?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, calendar

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Calendar1.SelectedDate);    

    }
    protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("1st");
    }
    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

In the above event i used break point at page_load and calender_selectionchanged  when i click any date on calender it first goes to page_load then to calender1_selectionchanged instead it should be in reverse order.

Also there is problem regarding selected date when i check in properties it shows correct date i.e. today's date 29/01/2011 .But when i print it it prints 1/1/0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Load` always becomes before `SelectionChanged` (a "postback event"). Why do you think they should occur in reverse order?

Comment: Actually i was thinkng changes made should be recorded first before these are loaded in page no?

Comment: Post data is loaded before the `Load` event, so your properties will have the values they should in `Load`, but the related events are only raised afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Matti Virkkunen for answer but Without calling the event how the changes made in that are can be called?

Comment: @ Matti Virkkunen: U are saying the properties are loaded in load event but events are raised after that and that confuse me that how could changes made in event are registered before these are registered?

Comment: @jagdeep: The properties are loaded *before* the `Load` event. I suggest you take a good long look at the link @TheGeek gave you. 1) The controls load their values from the POST data 2) `Load` is raised 3) events such as `Click` and `SelectionChanged` are raised. The events themselves have nothing to do with the controls loading their data, the events are there just to notify you of changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the [ASP.Net Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)  to see why Page_Load is called before your events.

Remove the Response.Write(Calendar1.SelectedDate); from your Page_Load event and place it under the Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now; line of code and see what happens.

Comment: Please provide the answer for 2nd query and thanks for last answer and thanks in advance for next.

Comment: The Page Life Cycle explains that.

Comment: Please see my amended answer.